# Authenticating for MS OneDrive

Tags: java, onedrive

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I would like to integrate OneDrive functionality. Unfortunately, I am not able to find some SDK which I can use for a webapp. Something in Maven repository will help. Can anyone tell me how I can authenticate and use some libraries for OneDrive.

Isn't there any SDK which I can directly put in POM.xml, like Google, dropbox and many other services have.

Here are some of the links I have tried:

1. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826531.aspx
2. http://www.tjeerd.net/2014/08/23/onedrive-api-restful-programming-in-java/
3. https://dev.onedrive.com/sample-code.htm

Samples in above are for android, nothing covers webapp. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

After almost five years I'd like to add that there is a Java SDK for MS Graph which will also cover your OneDrive access: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java

Probably you will already have solved your issues but for references. Add this to your POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
  <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And you can for example get all your files in the OneDrive like that:

```
Builder2 clientBuilder = GraphServiceClient.builder()
    .authenticationProvider(_accessTokenAuthProvider);

IHttpProvider httpProvider = DefaultClientConfig
    .createWithAuthenticationProvider(_accessTokenAuthProvider)
    .getHttpProvider(createOkHttpClientBuilder().build());
clientBuilder.httpProvider(httpProvider);

IGraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = clientBuilder.buildClient();
IDriveItemCollectionPage collectionPage = graphServiceClient.me().drive().root().children().buildRequest()
        .select("Id,Name,Folder,Size").get();
```

In the code snippet above, you would need to add the AuthenticationProvider which will implement `IAuthenticationProvider, ICoreAuthenticationProvider`. On executing you will get the `collectionPage` which will contain a list of `DriveItems`.

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can't verify, don't even work on same project. :-P

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Microsoft has a OneDrive SDK for web-application. However, you can easily use their Rest API to do all the work. The Rest APIs are pretty straight forward.
https://dev.onedrive.com/README.htm

They also have console to try out those apis
https://apigee.com/OneDrive/embed/console/OneDrive

Comment: Any examples you know for authentication and those REST calls?

Comment: You need to get authentication token via one of the flow described in this link https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/msa_oauth.htm. Once you get authentication or refresh token, you need to get access token (the steps also provided in the same link). Once you get the access token you can call their rest apis with access_token as query parameter.